# which.min does not produce any output

Tags: r

I have a dataset (Hospitals in the USA) where I need to get from a subset (Hospitals in a certain state) from the dataframe the row where a certain column (e.g. survival of Heart Attacks) has its minimum.

```
    test <- function(state, outcome) {
    ## Read outcome data
    ## Check that state and outcome are valid


      datasubset ## subsetting datta
      targetrow <- datasubset[which.min(datasubset$outcome),] ##get the row where "outcome" is minimum
      ##get hospital name where outcome is minimum
      ##get the minimum value
      ##just there to check if function works until this point
    }
```

If I run the function, the datasubset is printed but for the other two print commands I get
character(0) and
NULL

However, if I insert the code manually row for row and change state and outcome manually I get the right results. I do not really understand why it is not working when I use the function, but working when I write the commands directly into R. I suppose there is a problem with which.min ?
Thanks in advance for help

(I know this is part of the R-Course from the John Hopkins University, however course if over and I still want to get a working function! It is making me crazy)

the data looks like this:

```
      Hospital.Name                  State heart attack heart failure pneumonia
4262 CENTRAL VERMONT MEDICAL CENTER    VT         15.4          13.7      11.4
    enter code here
```

I could also upload it  if someone wants to reproduce it. 
EDIT: Code edited to avoid people just copying this code for their course.

Comment: if State is a column in data the try datasubset <- subset(data, data$State == state)..... Does this column exist datasubset$outcome? please let us know what values do state and outcome have, like is it an array

Comment: for debugging try `debug(best)` ... and read the documentation of `debug()` Whithout data it is not so easy to explore the problem

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this does not change something data subsetting works with my and your code. The datasubset$outcome column exists if you insert the right outcome in the function best("VT", "heart attack") e.g.

Comment: Can u upload the data, the data u showed here doesnt have outcome column so im confused what values it contains

Comment: http://www.file-upload.net/download-11083616/outcome-of-care-measures.csv.html

I will edit my complete code into the starting post, to make it more clear what I did. 

Outcome ar either "heart attack "heart failure" or "pneumonia" depending on what you put into the best function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error here is that you are using the $ operator for indexing.
datasubset$outcome refer to the column outcome (which you do not have in your data frame).

```
# Refer to column with the name that is stored in the variable outcome
datasubset[which.min(datasubset[,outcome]),]

# Refer to column that have the name outcome
datasubset[which.min(datasubset$outcome),]
```

Run this code to further understand the difference between $ and [ ]

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:5,y=6:10)

x <- "y"

df$x  #Gives x column
df[,x] #Gives y column
```

Comment: Ok now I understand the difference between $ and [] when it comes to function. I think I had a similar issue with [] and $ problem a couple of weeks ago but solved it without knowing why it worked after changing some code. Explains also why it works when I enter all the code manually - I do not use stored variable but used directly "heart attack" which is a "real" column
Thanks a lot!